# How to detach a child from one location in a widget tree and attach it another location with animation in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I was not sure how to express this question more clearly. We can consider this use case as a reference example.

Say we have a parent container with a column a it has two children RowWidget1 and RowWidget2. Below is a demo code we can refer.

```
class DemoWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const DemoWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DemoWidgetState createState() => _DemoWidgetState();
}

class _DemoWidgetState extends State<DemoWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          RowWidget1(),
          RowWidget2()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Our RowWidgets will be a basic row one with 3 containers in it and other with 2 containers. My goal is to do something like on tapping the last 3rd container of RowWidget1 it will be shifted to RowWidget2 with animation. Like detaching it from one widget and adding it to another with animation.

The goal is to create something like Hero animation but for our custom widget transition and not Page Navigation.

Below is an demo build of our expected result : ( I've emulated this one using Stack widget )

https://youtu.be/oyuw95LlsBw

Thankyou is advance for any sort of assistance.